# Django Guardian - Check Permission during filtering

Tags: django

Im using Django Guardian to use Instance Permissions.
It works well but I have a question about filtering.

Lets say we have a models called FakeItem.
Lets say we want to filter FakeItems list with only item with a specific permission.

```
@staticmethod
def purge_list(entity_list , userOrUsername, permission_name):
    requesting_user = userOrUsername
    if not isinstance(userOrUsername, User):
        requesting_user = User.objects.get(username = username)

    acl_listed = []
    total_rows = 0
    for entity in entity_list:
        if requesting_user.has_perm(entity, permission_name):
            acl_listed.append(entity)
            total_rows = total_rows + 1

    return { "list" :  acl_listed , "totals" : total_rows }
```

This is an example of a method to purge list from item the user can access.

Unfortunally this method is called AFTER I get the total list from database with a previous filter. I need to make a O(n) interation over the list to purge it.

I need something to purge the list directly in the original filter to optimize the query.

```
search_filter = Q()
search_filter = search_filter & Q(name__icontains = "foo")
search_filter = search_filter & Q(some_guardian_filter)
already_purged_list = FakeItem.objects.filter(search_filter)
```

Guardian's Documentation only explain how to use single method like has_perm etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest implementing the following way.

Create a QuerySet object using [get_objects_for_user](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user). It builds a queryset and adds all the filters for permission and for the given user. Then just filter the other values that you need. See the example below:

```
# returns the queryset filtered by permission and user
queryset = get_objects_for_user(user_object, permission_name)
return queryset.filter(name__icontains = "foo")
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed that metod. I see the thirth parameter can be a previous queryset. Fantastic!